# Como inserir valores no Laravel

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, laravel-5.6

Estou tentando usar o seguinte comando para inserir:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo2, campo4)
                     values(:campo1, :campo2, :campo3,'S')";
        $campos = array(
            ':campo1'      => $nome,
            ':campo2'      => $endreco,
            ':campo3'      => $bairro
        );
        $insert = DB::insert( $sql, $campos );
```

Mas está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (SQL: INSERT
>   INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo2) values(:campo1, :campo2, :campo3)

Não sei já tentei trocar o `insert` pelo `select` e nada

Pode me ajudar?

**[EDIT 1]**

```
public function salvar( Request $request ){

        $solicitante = $request->input( 'solicitante' );
        $usuario     = $request->input( 'usuario' );
        $setor       = $request->input( 'setor' );
        $descricao   = $request->input( 'descricao' );
        $ramal       = $request->input( 'ramal' );
        $observacao  = $request->input( 'observacao' );
        $codigo      = $this->proxRegistro();

        $sql = "insert into abertura_chamado 
                 (cd_os, dt_pedido, ds_servico, ds_observacao, nm_solicitante,TP_SITUACAO, CD_SETOR,
                  CD_MULTI_EMPRESA, CD_TIPO_OS, NM_USUARIO, DT_ULTIMA_ATUALIZACAO,
                  SN_SOL_EXTERNA, CD_OFICINA, SN_ORDEM_SERVICO_PRINCIPAL, 
                  SN_PACIENTE, DT_ENTREGA, TP_PRIORIDADE, SN_RECEBIDA,  SN_ETIQUETA_IMPRESSA,
                  SN_EMAIL_ENVIADO, TP_CLASSIFICACAO, CD_ESPEC, DS_RAMAL, TP_LOCAL
                 )
                 values 
                ( ?, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, 'S', ?, 
                 1, 30, ? , SYSDATE , 
                 'S', 14, 'S',  
                 'N', SYSDATE , ?, 'N',  'N',
                 'N',  'P', 31, ?, 'I')";
        $prioridade = 'E';
        $campos = array(
             $codigo,
             $descricao,
             $observacao,
             $solicitante,
             $setor,
             $usuario,
             $prioridade,
             $ramal

        );


        DB::insert( $sql, $campos );


    }
```

**[EDIT2]**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `Laravel` a forma de utilizar segue o exemplo:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);
```

no seu caso:

```
$sql    = "INSERT INTO tabela (campo1,campo2,campo3) values(?,?,?)";
$campos = array($nome,$endreco,$bairro);
$insert = DB::insert($sql,$campos);
```

pela sua pergunta talvez tenha confundido e poderia fazer assim também:

```
DB::table('tabela')->insert(
    [
         'campo1' => $nome,
         'campo2' => $endereco,
         'campo3' => $bairro
    ]
);
```

ou seja, existe algumas formas de fazer um `Insert` pelo `Laravel`.

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts)

Comment: A mensagem de erro continua

Comment: @adventistaam coloque na sua pergunta o seu verdadeiro código! o que proposto a você é mediante a documentação não tem como errar!

Comment: Pronto adicionei o verdadeiro codigo

Comment: @adventistaam cole a imagem do erro na sua pergunta!

Comment: já adicionei a imagem

Comment: então o erro é na Str onde se usa isso? @adventistaam

Comment: Desculpa não entendi sua pergunta

Comment: O problema não naquele código @adventistaam onde você usa `Str`???

Comment: Na verdade o único comando str que eu uso é aquele comando sql